# How do I explore the Ubuntu 12.04 partition in Windows 7?

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-7

I've got **Windows 7 (64-bit)** and **Ubuntu 12.04 (64-bit)** installed on different partitions. When I'm booted in Ubuntu I'm able to explore my Windows partition. How can I explore my Ubuntu partition when I'm booted in Windows?

If it's possible I'd like to have the partition appear under the Hard Disc Drives in Computer.

How would I do this or something similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu uses ext4 for its file system.  Unfortunately, this is incompatible with Windows 7.  There are ext2 and ext3 compatibility layers you can obtain and install, but not ext4.  Unfortunately, you'll need to create a shared partition with NTFS to share files between Windows and Ubuntu, or use Ubuntu to access the Windows partition directly.

Comment: Thanks! So, if I was to install Ubuntu selecting ext3 instead of ext4 would it appear under Hard Disc Drives in Windows 7?

Comment: No, you'd still need to go find and install the compatibility layer/drivers/software (but I don't recommend this, since Windows doesnt like Linux style permissions). And ext3 is not preferred over ext4. The normal solutoin nowadays is to have separate partitions for data sharing, since Windows 7 can't handle ext4 nor can it handle Linux file permissions very well.